# Creating a grid for hyperparameter tunning fixing some parameters

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidymodels

I have a `grid_regular` for a dt like this:

```
tree_grid <- grid_regular(cost_complexity(), tree_depth(), min_n())
```

However, I only want to use `tree_depth` in a certain range of values, let's say, 4 to 6, so the model can be easily plotted.

Basically fixing the top and bottom values for the `min_n()` parameter.

Is there any way to do it with `tidymodels`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the grid definition, you can easily set ranges for any parameter like this:

```
tree_grid <- grid_regular(cost_complexity(),
                          tree_depth(
                            range = c(4L, 6L)
                            ),
                          min_n()
                          )
```